# check if an event has happened before performing an action in NodeRed

Tags: node-red

I have a door sensor that detects if its open or closed. I also have a camera which detects motion and sends an mqtt message when the motions stops.

If the doors opens, the camera detects movements and, sometime later, I receive the mqtt message. However, if I walk nearby the door, the camera also detects movement and sends the mqtt message.

What I am trying to do in NodeRed is to perform an action when I receive the camera motion message, but only if the door was open .

To do so, I have connected the door sensor to a `change` node to create a message which represents "door has been open". However, when I receive the mqtt message, I have no idea how to check if the door was open to continue with the flow

[image]

Basically, my question can be summarized as how can I check is something has happened to continue or stop the flow

Comment: Look for "context" in the docs

Comment: I was trying to avoid global style variables. Coming from a C++ background, I feel uncomfortable using them. Furthermore, it kind of hides the dependency between nodes, no?

Comment: You have to store state somewhere, context is where you store state. (I suggest you store the timestamp of the last door event, so you can decide what time period to associate the 2 events over)

Comment: I see. I was actually checking the `join` node to try to create a message with the door_open + the camera message. No success yet though, I guess I will have a look at the context approach otherwise

Comment: Make sure you set different topics on the 2 input messages for the join node, it will help. You might be able to do something with a trigger node to add a timeout, but I'd still try context first

Answer (score 0):

Give me your node-red source. I can fix for you.
You can use 'function' and 'delay' node for it.
Could you upload your node-red flow?

Try this one first.

```
[
{
    "id": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "stackoverflow",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "0247562ae8b3c9ed",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "door open",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 140,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "380af527db692157"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "380af527db692157",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "door open",
    "func": "global.set(\"DoorOpen\",1);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 300,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8848430d64746121",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "door close",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 140,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        [
            "8f6ce1d3d43cdf9d"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8f6ce1d3d43cdf9d",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "door close",
    "func": "global.set(\"DoorOpen\", 0);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 310,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "7166a60ba150e1e9",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "Used Inject node Instead of 'Door sensor'",
    "info": "",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "5c4e6ebc4448deaf",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "Used inject node instead of 'Motion sensor'",
    "info": "",
    "x": 240,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "64a58da41010748c",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 140,
    "y": 300,
    "wires": [
        [
            "7cf32612d4e3cb63"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "7cf32612d4e3cb63",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "motion sensor",
    "func": "var door = global.get(\"DoorOpen\");\n\nif(door==1){\n msg.payload=\"door opened. You can add your function here\";\n}\nelse if(door==0){\n msg.payload = \"door closed. You can add your function here\";\n}\n\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 320,
    "y": 300,
    "wires": [
        [
            "0b9d0ad34f867991"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "67b509b7f84f4cc2",
    "type": "comment",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "Stackoverflow link",
    "info": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340554/check-if-an-event-has-happened-before-performing-an-action-in-nodered/74397929#74397929",
    "x": 170,
    "y": 40,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "0b9d0ad34f867991",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "82b48005d8d8eb1a",
    "name": "debug 19",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 480,
    "y": 300,
    "wires": []
}
```

]

Comment: Thank you for offering to help. However, answers on this site are intended to be useful to people in the future with similar problems. If you can identify the important change, and even better explain why it's important, it would make this answer much better.